# Excel 2007: Need a count when comparing differences in two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one column that contains budgets and another that contains actuals.  How can I get a count in a cell above the actuals column that will tell me how many of them are under their budgets?   Example:  If 10 out of 100 of them are under budget, what formula would I write that would give me a total of "10"?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B101<A2:A101))
```

Where your actuals are in `B2:B101` and the budgets are in `A2:A101`.